# Formulas for higher order cumulants

Tags: moments, signal-processing, bivariate, cumulants

I want to calculate higher-order joint [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Joint_cumulants) for 2 variables. I calculated the higher order single-variable and bivariate moments numerically. Now I need to combine them into cumulants (upto the 6th order cumulant, eg k_{3,3})

However, surprisingly, I was unable to find the equations for this anywhere online. Wikipedia (see link above) gives the general formula and provides a few examples for joint cumulants. Also, the [summary wolfram site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulant.html) gives a few more examples for bivariate cumulants. However, I was not able to find any comprehensive table that gives all the equations. I feel I understand the formula and the partition concept, but it is tedious to do all the calculations by hand and I dont trust myself not to make an error.

My questions are:

1) Do these equations exist anywhere online?

2) Is there an easy way to get these equations using computing software like Python or Matlab?

3) If not, what else can I do to get them?

Thanks!

Comment: Stuart & Ord (*Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics,* Fourth Edition) give these relations in formula (3.81).  It expresses the bivariate cumulants in terms of the bivariate central moments.  For instance, it includes $$\kappa_{33} = \mu_{33} - 3\mu_{31}\mu_{02} - \cdots + 12 \mu_{11}^3.$$  *Mathematica* will [compute them](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulant.html).

Comment: @whuber, thanks for comment! Unfortunately I don't have access to the Stuart & Ord book, nor do I have a Mathematica/MathStatica license. I was hoping there would be something available online or in open-source software...

Answer (score 2):

The joint bivariate moment generating function is

$$M(t,s) = E[e^{t X + s Y}]$$

and the cumulant generating function is it's logarithm

$$K(t,s) = \log E[e^{t X + s Y}]$$

The Taylor series expressions of the moment generating function is

$$M(t,s) = \sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{N_0}^2} \frac{\sigma_{k,l}}{k!l!} t^k s^l  $$

where $\sigma_{k,l} = E[X^kY^l]$ are the raw moments of the variables.

The logarithm can be expressed similarly as a power series for this we make use of

$$\log(1+u) =  \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m-1}\frac{u^m}{m}$$

the

$$\begin{array}{}
K(t,s) &= &\log\left(M(t,s) \right)\\
&=&  \log\left( \sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{N_0}^2} \frac{\sigma_{k,l}}{k!l!} t^k s^l \right) \\
&=&  \log\left(1 + \left(-1 + \sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{N_0}^2} \frac{\sigma_{k,l}}{k!l!} t^k s^l \right)\right) \\
&=& \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m-1}\frac{1}{m} \left(-1+  \sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{N_0}^2} \frac{\sigma_{k,l}}{k!l!} t^k s^l \right)^m \\
&=&  \sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{N_0}^2} \frac{\kappa_{k,l}}{k!l!} t^k s^l
\end{array}$$

Where the coefficients $\kappa_{k,l}$ in the power series are the cumulants and these can be found by writing out the before last expression.

That expression is a bit nasty and needs something like [Faà Di Bruno's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) but multivariate.

In the case of $\kappa_{3,3}$ we can find out all the ways, for $m$ from $1$ to $6$, that the we get powers $t^3s^3$

$$\begin{array}{}
&&&
&(\frac{\sigma_{0,1}}{1} t^0s^1& + &\frac{\sigma_{0,2}}{2} t^0s^2& + &\frac{\sigma_{0,3}}{6} t^0s^3& + \\
&&\frac{\sigma_{1,0}}{1} t^1s^0& +
&\frac{\sigma_{1,1}}{1} t^1s^1& + &\frac{\sigma_{1,2}}{2} t^1s^2& + &\frac{\sigma_{1,3}}{6} t^1s^3& + \\
&&\frac{\sigma_{2,0}}{2} t^2s^0&+
&\frac{\sigma_{2,1}}{2} t^2s^1& + &\frac{\sigma_{2,2}}{4} t^2s^2& + &\frac{\sigma_{2,3}}{12} t^2s^3& + \\
&&\frac{\sigma_{3,0}}{6} t^3s^0& +
&\frac{\sigma_{3,1}}{6} t^3s^1& + &\frac{\sigma_{3,2}}{12} t^3s^2& + &\frac{\sigma_{3,3}}{36} t^3s^3)^m&
\end{array}$$

Or not, I have to rethink this a bit. The expression is gonna contain a large sum with products of 6 terms $\sigma_{1,1}\sigma_{1,1}\sigma_{1,1}\sigma_{1,1}\sigma_{1,1}\sigma_{1,1}$ down to 1 term $\sigma_{3,3}$

Anyways, this is the derivation that is behind the table that you found and posted in the other answer.

Comment: The expression in terms of central moments seem to be simpler because the $\mu_{0,1}$ cancel out and you will not get products of 6 terms and for the n-th order cumulants, products with $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ central moments are the max.

Comment: So are the above formulas correct in approximation then?

Comment: @DankMasterDan the formulas are correct but they are laborious to execute.

Comment: #@DankMasterDan when you refer to the formulas from your answer, with the $M_{ij}$, then they are not correct when you mean with those $M_{ij}$ the bivariate raw or central moment.

Answer (score 0):

so I found what I was looking for in some academic papers. For example, see:

[Abdelmutalab, Ameen, Khaled Assaleh, and Mohamed El-Tarhuni. "Automatic modulation classification based on high order cumulants and hierarchical polynomial classifiers." Physical Communication 21 (2016): 10-18.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1874490716301094)

They provide equations for cumulants of *complex variables* upto the 6th order:

[image]

Comment: What does M stand for in the above relations?  M is not the bivariate central moments - and I am at a loss as to what the table above is showing at all!?

Comment: @wolfies they are the raw moments $M_{kl} = \mathbb{E}(X^kY^l)$.

Comment: Hi @SextusEmpiricus  Perhaps they are _meant_ to be the Raw Moments, but if so most of those formulae are incorrect. First, they appear to be assuming that all first moments are zero (which is not generally appropriate). Even then, some are obviously incorrect. The first term of $C_{41}$ cannot be $M_{40}$ but must be $M_{41}$  ... and the minus 3 term should be minus 6. The $C_{42}$ is also obviously wrong as the second term on the RHS $M_{20}$ does not have the required weight, and the absolute value is superfluous. I can't reproduce any of the higher others either. That is why I asked.

Comment: @wolfies you are right, they can't be central moment and neither raw moments.